# Morris charts positioning on a cell phone

Tags: html, morris.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can get my Morris charts to be responsive on a mobile phone. I want them to go underneath each other when on a small screen. Any ideas?

```
<div class="container" style= "float: left; width: 50%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>Your activities:</h2>  
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="user_activity-donut"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style= "float: right; width: 50%">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>What others do:</h2>  
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="global_activity-donut"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Following is the .js part.

```
$.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js',function(){
$.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.0/morris.min.js',function(){
      Morris.Donut({
        element: 'user_activity-donut',
        data: [
         {label: "Jogging", value: 50},
         {label: "Sailing", value: 20},
         {label: "Walking", value: 15}
        ]
      });
      Morris.Donut({
        element: 'global_activity-donut',
        data: [
         {label: "Jogging", value: 30},
         {label: "Sailing", value: 5},
         {label: "Walking", value: 65}
        ]
      });
});
});
```

Comment: If I where you I should use css `media query`. When On small screen (your phone) `display` the charts as `block` and while on a big screen `display` them for example `inline-block`. Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp .

Comment: is Morris charts related at all to Morris Dancing?

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your head tag

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" />
```

then add the folowing after the labels and values
resize: true,
redraw: true,

Example:

```js
Morris.Donut({
        element: 'user_activity-donut',
        data: [
         {label: "Jogging", value: 50},
         {label: "Sailing", value: 20},
         {label: "Walking", value: 15}
        ]
resize:true,
redraw:true,
      });
```